# trying to go to next screen after user taps on cell in table

Tags: swift2, ios9

In a previous post, the below code was given as an answer to the question i have.  When i tried using that code and replacing with my variables, etc I am getting an error.

'selectedValue' - error is "value of type ViewController has no member 'selectedValue'"

what does selectedValue represent?

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender:     AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == "Details" {
        let destination = segue.destinationViewController as?     SecondViewController
        let cell = sender as UITableViewCell
        let selectedRow = tableView.indexPathForCell(cell)!.row
        destination!.selectedValue = items[selectedRow]
    }
}
```

Comment: What i have is a recipe directory and each row (directory item) will take you to another table view controller specific to that directory item.  So, i have 7 items and 7 new view controllers.. hope that clarifies things a bit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code looks like the code you'd use to pass the selected data from one view controller to another when a cell is selected, am I right?

In your code, `selectedValue` should be a variable declared in `SecondViewController`. It is *where you're passing the data to*.

Comment: Ok of what type should this variable be?  To do this for 7 segues, would i need to do a for loop in this code?

Comment: It would be of the type that `items` is an array of. I don't think you would use a for-loop. If you want to pass data through seven screens, you would need to define `selectedValue` in each screen and set its value in prepareForSegue for each screen, too.

Comment: Ok thanks. I will try that. Thanks for your quick response :)

Comment: I have declared a variable - var passedValue : String! on every table view controller being used.  Below is the code i am using: 

 if indexPath.row == 0 {
            
            // Get Cell Label
            let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow!
            let currentCell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) as UITableViewCell!
            
            valueToPass = currentCell.textLabel!.text
            performSegueWithIdentifier("toCMT", sender: self)
            
        }

How to i do this with 7 different segues from this view controller?

Comment: if i declare passedValue = [String]() like i declared my list of directories in parse = var directory = [String](), I get an error on the line with 'valueToPass = currentCell.textLabel!.text' : cannot assign value of type 'String?' to type '[String]'

Comment: if indexPath.row == 0 { // Get Cell Label let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow! let currentCell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) as UITableViewCell! valueToPass = currentCell.textLabel!.text performSegueWithIdentifier("toCMT", sender: self) } .... I do this code in an if .. else if ... for 7 different segues from the directory table view controller.  it works but any ideas as to how i shorten this down?

Comment: I have updated the previous code to a switch but i am sure there is something else i can do.  What happens if i update parse (data is stored) and i only have 7 cases?